# Why Rails does not add my record to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my view, I added:

```
=form_for(:user, url: new_user_path) do
    .col-xs-2= text_field_tag(:name, nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Name")
    = submit_tag('OK', class: "btn btn-default")
```

In my UsersController:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.save
  redirect_to @user
end
```

where

```
private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name)
end
```

I have on my `users` table the `name` field.

And in my `routes` I have these lines:

```
post 'users/create'
post 'users/new'
```

Can anyone say, why it does not add my records to database? I cannot find where is my mistake

Comment: Did you check your log for error messages?

Comment: Did you try to use save! instead of save and see if you get any meaningful error messages?

Comment: @MarsAtomic no, I do not have any errors in my logs

Comment: @roychri nothing again. I do not get errors in my logs =/

Comment: My guess is that you have presence validation on user name. In which case, your form is wrong. It provides `params[:name]`, but what you need is `params[:user][:name]`. Hint: the error is in the line with `text_field_tag`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev in `text_field_tag`? So in my `:name` there?

Comment: @Doe: should be `f.text_field :name`. You use `form_for`. Actually _use_ its advantages (such as building controls with proper form names)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev but I'm using HAML, so I do not have |f| there

Comment: @Doe HAML does not prevent that in the slightest.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I see. But I still do not have any record in my db table =/

Comment: Must be something else is wrong, then

Comment: @SergioTulentsev when I press submit button it redirects me to `/users/new` page and there I have another form. Can be that a problem???

Comment: wait a second, what's up with `url: new_user_path` in the form?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what's wrong?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I saw it in tutorial, there was `users_path`, but in my case it redirects to update page, that's why I wrote `new_user_path`

Comment: @Doe: yeah, that's the problem. You post to `users/new`, but that action doesn't save anything, obviously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125623/discussion-between-doe-and-sergio-tulentsev).